# Reading files and passing parameters to structs array in a C function

Tags: c

It's my first post here in StackOverflow! I'm trying to write a code that reads an assembly code and stores it in an array of structs. I implemented a function that does this. Inside the function, it seems the values have correctly been passed to the array of structs, as I tried to see the values in the structs with some `printf`. But when I try to see the same values outside the function (so, I used some `printf` in the main function for this), the values printed are absolutely wrong!

Obs: The logic of the code is not complete, I'm just trying to solve the file reading problem for now.
Obs2: the .txt file I'm trying to read is:

oi  MOV s1,s2

tchau   ADD s3,s4

1   sub s5,s6

```
void loader(struct instructionEmMnemonico mnemonicoInstru[500]) {
    FILE* arquivo;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char letra = '0';
    int endline = 0;
    int mnemonico = 0;
    char line[90];
    char *token, *result;

    arquivo = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
        if(arquivo == NULL) {
            printf("Arquivo nao pode ser aberto\n");
        }
        while(!feof(arquivo)) {
            fgets(line, 90, arquivo);
            printf("%c-----------\n",line[0]);
            if(line[0] != ' ' || line[0] != '\n' || line[0] != '\t') {
                token = strtok(line,", \n\t");
                mnemonicoInstru[i].label = token;
                printf("%s\n",mnemonicoInstru[i].label);
                token = strtok(NULL,", \n\t");
                mnemonicoInstru[i].mnemonico = token;
                printf("%s\n",mnemonicoInstru[i].mnemonico);
                token = strtok(NULL,", \n\t");
                mnemonicoInstru[i].operando1 = token;
                printf("%s\n",mnemonicoInstru[i].operando1);
                token = strtok(NULL,", \n\t");
                mnemonicoInstru[i].operando2 = token;
                printf("%s\n",mnemonicoInstru[i].operando2);
            } else {
                token = strtok(line,", \n\t");
                mnemonicoInstru[i].label = token;
                printf("%s\n",mnemonicoInstru[i].label);
                token = strtok(NULL,", \n\t");
                mnemonicoInstru[i].mnemonico = token;
                printf("%s\n",mnemonicoInstru[i].mnemonico);

                token = strtok(NULL,", \n\t");
                mnemonicoInstru[i].operando1 = token;
                printf("%s\n",mnemonicoInstru[i].operando1);

                token = strtok(NULL,", \n\t");
                mnemonicoInstru[i].operando2 = token;
                printf("%s\n",mnemonicoInstru[i].operando2);

                token = strtok(NULL,", \n\t");
                mnemonicoInstru[i].operando3 = token;
                printf("%s\n",mnemonicoInstru[i].operando3);
            }
            i++;
        }
    fclose(arquivo);
}


int main() {
    struct instructionEmMnemonico programa[500];

    loader(programa);
    printf("-----\n");
    printf("%c--------\n",programa[2].label[0]);
    printf("%s---\n",programa[2].mnemonico);
    printf("%s--\n",programa[2].operando1);
    printf("%s-\n",programa[2].operando2);
return 0;
}
```

In the `printf` inside the function "loader", the results are correct, but the `printf` in the main function doesn't make any sense!

Comment: This is not a minimal working example.  You could reduce it to reading just one or two fields, and you have not defined `struct instructionEmMnemonico`.

Comment: Sorry, I will pay more attention on this next time! :)

Comment: `while(!feof(arquivo)) {`  <<-- seen this one before... https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/905902

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are assigning pointers.
`mnemonicoInstru[i].label = token;`

since `token` is pointer to local variable `line` you have undefined behavior when you access it outside the `loader` function.

Copy the actual contents.

`mnemonicoInstru[i].label = strdup(token);`